BLE: Measure Respiratory rate or breathing rate from bluetooth low energy Device
I want a Bluetooth low energy device that measures Respiratory rate (Breathing rate) in breaths per minute. I don't see any Service or characteristic in Bluetooth SIG assigned numbers and no resources.
Some article suggests to calculate it from heart rate monitor but I don't see anything that tells how to do it.
Any help is appreciated.

This might help: TI Heart Rate Sensor
From the link above:

Heart Rate Measurement (UUID: 0x2A37)
This characteristic is used to notify simulated heart rate measurements with default size of 1 byte.


Thanku, but this actually measures heart rate. I want to calculate Respiratory rate or breathing rate.

I also couldn't find any sensor/device like the one I mentioned in my answer to measure respiratory rate but there are many tutorials online which you can follow to make one if required/possible then using ESP32, etc. you can pass this data over BLE.
